# Can any one tell cron expression value(ex: 0/15 * * * *) for scheduling job in pcf?

Tags: java, cron, job-scheduling, cron-task

I want to run the job every 3hr 30min(Ex:1:00pm next 4:30pm next 8:00pm next 11.30pm so on...)

Comment: https://crontab.guru/ http://www.cronmaker.com/ https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 0):

Classic cron expressions cannot express time intervals like "3 hours 30 minutes".

One workaround is to schedule a cron job for every 30 minutes (`0,30 * * * *`). And, inside your job put additional logic to check if the job should run or abort.